# Como eu posso substituir um erro por um print sem encerrar o programa? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Se eu criar uma variável com um input que só recebe números inteiros (int) e colocar outros tipos de números ou até letras, vai gerar um erro e o programa vai encerrar.

Queria saber se tem uma forma de substituir o erro, por uma mensagem de erro personalizada, sem encerrar o programa.

Comment: Tenho certeza que é duplicata, mas não achei a pergunta já existente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tratar o erro com um bloco try/except, algo assim:

```
def entrar_dados():
    try:
        numero = int(input('Entre com um numero: '))
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Voce nao digitou um numero valido', e)

    # Continuação do código
```

Adicionando mais regras ao seu programa após a captura de valor ou erro, ele continuará executando normalmente.

Comment: É melhor especificar a exceção `ValueError` no `except` para garantir que está capturando a exceção correta.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss agradeço pela sugestão. Editei a resposta.